# Adding a new column in pandas in a specific place

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**I tried to add a new column in this code but i didn't succeed:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel("JET.xlsx")

col=df.reindex(columns=['accountNumber','documentNumber','amountLC','postingDate','financialPeriod','fiscalYear','createdBy','debitCreditIndicator','headerDescription','customText','companyCode','creationDate','creationTime','documentCurrency','localCurrency','documentType','lineDescription'])

df1=pd.read_excel('TB.xlsx',sheet_name='TB',index_col=0)

jet=df[['accountNumber']]
tb=df1[['accountNumber']]

dataframes=[jet,tb]

join = pd.concat(dataframes)

duplic=join.drop_duplicates(subset='accountNumber')
duplic=duplic.sort_values(by='accountNumber')
duplic["#|#"]="#|#"
duplic['accountNumber']=duplic['accountNumber'].astype(str)

caracter=duplic['accountNumber'].str[0]

duplic['accountType']=np.where(caracter > '5', 'P','B')
duplic['accountNumber']=duplic['accountNumber'].astype(int)

gla=duplic.merge(df1.loc[:,["accountNumber","accountName"]],how='right',left_on="accountNumber",right_on="accountNumber")
gla.drop_duplicates(subset=['accountNumber'],keep='first', inplace=True)
gla.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=0)
```

The code is working, but I need to add a column between column accountType and accountName.
Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must 
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_loc` and `insert` to complete your task. This can be achieved as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe with two mentioned columns
df = pd.DataFrame({"accountNumber": [1, 2], "accountName": [3,4]})

# find the index no
index_no = df.columns.get_loc("accountName")
print("Index of column in given dataframe is : {}".format(index_no))

# Insert new Column
df.insert(index_no, 'NEW COL', -1)

print(df)
```